# Implementation of Charts in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, charts, bar-chart, pie-chart

In my application i have to implement Pie and bar charts with animation like HighCharts in java. Please suggest any SDK air framework to implement moving charts with good quality. Any source code will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried [coreplot](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer this Pie Chart sample demo .  https://github.com/yuanlizbyy/PieChartDemo